# Lower boundary of quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

I have a quadratic form $x^TAx$ where $x$ is an $n \times 1$ vector and $A$ is a positive definite matrix in the sense that it has only positive eigenvalues. Am I right to say that $||x^TAx|| \ge \lambda_{min}(A) ||x||^2$ where $\lambda_{min}(A)$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $A$? If not, is there another lower boundary?

Comment: It is correct - except that you should replace $\|x\|$ by $\|x\|^2$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp yeah, right, my mistake

Comment: You never said that $A$ is symmetric.  By your definition, is the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&10\\0&1}
$$
positive definite? If so, then the answer is no.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $A$ is not symmetric. In this case, is there another lower boundary?

Comment: Oh sorry. For me, positive definite always includes symmetric/selfadjoint.

Comment: @Controller I'm guessing that the definition of positive definite you should be using is that "$A$ is positive definite if and only if for all non-zero $x \in \Bbb R^n$, we have
$x^TAx > 0$".  Please check your notes and verify that this is the case.  If it is the case, then my matrix $A$ is disqualified.

Comment: @Controller if you mean what I think you mean (as in, you're using the definition that I've given), then the correct lower bound is 
$$
x^TAx \geq \frac 12 \lambda_{min}(A + A^T)\|x\|^2
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes that is the case. In this case, is it guaranteed that $\lambda_{min}(Α+Α^Τ)>0$?

Comment: Yes, this is guaranteed as a consequence of that definition. It is also guaranteed that the eigenvalues of $A + A^T$ are real.

Comment: Shouldn't $||x^TAx||$ just be the absolute value since it is a scalar?  the norm of a scalar is just its absolute value @Controller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bound you've given works specifically in the case that $A$ is *symmetric* and positive definite. For the "asymmetric, positive definite" case, we have the more general bound
$$
x^TAx =  x^T \left( \frac{A + A^T}{2} \right)x \geq \frac 12 \lambda_{min}(A + A^T)\|x\|^2
$$

Comment: Hello @Omnomnomnom, do you mind showing a proof for this?

Comment: @Hunle the proof is a bit too long for a comment and I'd rather not edit such an old answer.  If you're interested, I suggest you post a new question that points to my answer.  If I find the time, I might put down an answer myself.